# How to compare 2 JSON schemas using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 JSON schemas as below -

**df1.printSchema()**

```
# root
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

**df2.printSchema()**

```
#root
# |-- name: array (nullable = true)
# |-- gender: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

How can I compare these 2 schemas and highlight the differences using pyspark as I am using pyspark-sql to load data from the JSON file into a DF.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear what do you mean by "compare", the following code will give you the fields (FieldType) which are on DF2 and not on DF1.

```
set(df2.schema.fields) - set(df1.schema.fields)
```

Set will take your list and truncate the duplicates.

Comment: I want to return the differences in another DataFrame like below. How can this be done? - column                df1          df2     diff                       
    name:               string       array     type                             
    gender:              N/A         integer   new column

Comment: It is **still** unclear what do you want. Can you specify it better?

Comment: I basically want to display the differences between above 2 json structures. By looking at above there are 2 changes in df2 when compared to df1 i.e, gender is a new field in df2 and also name is changed from string to array. I want to list these changes. Looking for a way how to achieve this. Hope it is clear?

Answer (score 0):

I find the following one line code useful and neat. I also provides you the two-directional differences at a column level

```
set(df1.schema).symmetric_difference(set(df2.schema))
```